# How to enable unity plugin without ccsm

Tags: unity, compiz

I installed Ubuntu 13.10 on an HP Compaq D530 cmt and I can only see the desktop pic and I have found out that I don't have the unity plugin enabled. I went [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears) to see what this person did. I got ccsm and I have no way of applying changes to the unity plugin, so I can enable it, but that does no good because the changes don't take effect. If I leave ccsm and come back the unity plugin is uncheckmarked. I really do not know what to do, some people have mentioned there are missing drivers for my PC also, but when I go to the update manager and go to drivers it says there are no drivers available for this computer. I don't know what is stopping me from enabling the unity plugin, can anyone tell me a command I can use in terminal to fix my problems. Thanks

Comment: No, I don't know of any hardware that needs drivers.

Comment: Please don't open a question twice. Edit or comment on the primary question.